# Saving an image in an HTML page using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to save an image using Javascript on a button click in HTML using the following code:

```
function saveImage(anImage) {

if (typeof anImage== 'object') 
  Image= anImage.src;  
window.win = open(anImage);           
setTimeout('win.document.execCommand("SaveAs")', 500);
}
```

it works fine when I run the code from my local PC (i.e. it pops a new window and prompts me to save the image as a png file) , but when I deploy it to a server it pops the new window but it tries to save the page instead of the image (it opens a dialog box asking to save an htm file)

any reason ?

Comment: What debugging and research have you done so far?

Comment: Most probably it's because the content type is set to `HTML` in the popup window and if you are able to set/change the content type `Content-Type: image/png'` then it may work but I'm afraid that you can't set the content type using `javascript`.

Answer (score 0):

John Culviner wrote a jquery plugin that handles this.

https://github.com/johnculviner/jquery.fileDownload